# how to count together the size of files when they are created in foreach loop

Tags: php, count

i am using a folder in which user can upload files. These files are outputted with the name and the size.

```
$dir = "users/$UserName";
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach ($files as $file) {
if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
echo sizeFormat(filesize($dir . '/' . $file));
}
```

So my output looks like this:

koala.jpg => 600kB

jellyfish.jpg => 600kB

tulips.jpg => 500kB

How can i count all the sizes together?

Something like: Toal size all files: 1700kB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$dir = "users/$UserName";
$files = scandir($dir);
$total = 0;

foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        $total += filesize($dir . '/' . $file);
        echo sizeFormat(filesize($dir . '/' . $file));
    }
}
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... just add the sizes together!?

Assuming your code works, here's a mockup how to do it:

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        $current = filesize($dir . '/' . $file);
        $total += $current;
        echo sizeFormat($current);
    } 
}
echo "total: ".sizeFormat($total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming you have the sizeFormat function somewhere)

```
$dir = "users/$UserName";
$files = scandir($dir);
$size = 0;

foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        $size += filesize($dir . '/' . $file);
    }
}

echo sizeFormat($size);
```